# is it recommended to use WP_List_Table?

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

At moment i am developing a Wordpress-Plugin where I have to print a custom table in the admin-menu. After a short research I found the solution with WP_List_Table. But on the Class Reference from Wordpress I saw that the class is marked as private, that means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table

So is it recommended to use this class or should I print the table with "plain" php?

Comment: The advice in your link sounds good to me: either use it and accept the risk that it might break at some point (but it's been 7+ years) or make a renamed copy of the class in your plugin and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The thing we have to say first here is that Codex officially informs that:

> This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not
>   intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to
>   change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would
>   still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and
>   distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.

So at first glance, it's a bad idea to use it in your plugin. But...

It still is very handy class and it saves you a lot of coding. It also makes very easy to code UI that is consistent with other WP parts...

Another reason to use it is that a lot of plugins do.

So yes - I would go for it and use it in my plugin. But I'd have on my mind that it's a little bit risky and maybe someday my plugin will stop working because of WP update - so I'll have to test it against new versions or track changes in this class.